# Why in Android documentation Activity classes have static modifier

Tags: java, android, android-activity, static

If we open android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#Deliver) we will see that `Activity` classes have **static** modifier:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity {...}
```

I'm used to declaring **Activities** without **static** modifier:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {...}
```

What is the reason behind using **static** modifier in `Activity` class declaration?

**UPDATE**:

The `static` modifiers have been removed from the documentation.

Comment: Documentation bug. Sadly, they are not rare. That's not to say that you can't have a static nested `Activity` subclass, but it's pretty clear that that's not what they intended there.

Comment: You'd normally only use the `static` modifier for classes when declaring an inner class that does not need to be linked to the declaring outer class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Documentation bug. Sadly, they are not rare. You'd normally only use the **static** modifier for classes when declaring an inner class that does not need to be linked to the declaring outer class, for example:

```
public class OuterClass {
    // ...

    // static inner class has no reference to outer class
    public static class InnerClass { 
        // ...
    }
}
```